# Добавить задержку в login.php

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

Добрый день вопрос в основном по nginx.
Есть код в файле login.php:

```
<?php

# ... Тут много всякого

/*
 * В случае успешного входа
 * так и в случае ошибки
 * добавляем тайм-аут 1..2 секунды
 */
usleep(1e6,2e6);
echo $answer; # Отправляем результат клиенту
```

Все это работает отлично до того случая пока не придет какой-нибудь botnet и не начнет перебирать пароли. Тогда php-fpm затыкается по кол-ву процессов.

Собственно вопрос в том как сделать так, что-бы задержку обеспечивал nginx, а не php.

То есть идея в том, что-бы в php передать информацию nginx-у о том что здесь нужен тайм-аут.
Так-же возможна настройка location-а в nginx-е в котором производится задержка между получением ответа от php и передачей его клиенту.

**UPDATE** приблизительное решение

Посмотрел в сторону [ngx_http_perl_module](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_perl_module.html), получилось примерно так (пришлось переименовть login.php в ogin.php:

```
# файл nginx.conf
http {
    perl_modules /path/to;
    perl_require login.pm;
    # …
    server {
        # …
        location = /login.php {
           perl login::login;
        }
        location = /ogin.php {
           internal;
           fastcgi_cache off;
           fastcgi_pass php;
        }
    }
}

# файл login.pm
package login;
use strict;
use nginx;

sub ogin_php {
    shift->internal_redirect("/ogin.php?");
    return OK;
}
sub login {
    my ($r) = @_;

    if ($r->request_method eq "POST") {
        $r->sleep(1000+rand(1000), \&ogin_php);
        return OK;
    }
    &ogin_php;  
}
1;
__END__
```

Как изобразить что-то подобное на lua пока не сообразил. Под боевой нагрузкой не тестировал, но ab и siege отрабатывают нормально.

Comment: Возможно, Вам поможет директива Nginx send_timeout http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#send_timeout, но я бы "копал" приложение - например, добавил бы CSRF защиту в эту форму...а лучше во все

Comment: Насколько я понял, это не совсем то, это не задержка передачи, время за которое передается ответ клиенту, если не получилось - рвем соединение.

CSRF - это хорошо, но он легко обходится ботнетом, и вообще с тем что я сталкиваюсь - достаточно разумно, то есть оно сначала получает сессию, а потом отправляет login/password, так что CSRF обойдут достаточно просто. Нужен именно защитный timeout

Comment: Да, правильно поняли, это Вам не подойдет.

Comment: блокировка в nginx-овском обработчике противоречит всей природе nginx. вам нужно ограничивать количество запросов в единицу времени, сделать это можно с помощью `ngx_http_limit_req_module` или `ngx_http_limit_conn_module`

Comment: Я тут погуглил и оказалось, что fail2ban можно настроить на определенный URL. Вот ссылка, там вордпресс wp-login.php DDoSят https://debian.pro/1223

Comment: fail2ban не эффективен при большом ботнете и малом кол-ве запросов с каждого IP

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я помню, из коробки в nginx ничего подходящего для Вас нет. Единственное что более-менее подходит - ограничение количества запросов в единицу времени, в разных вариациях. В [документации](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html) подробное описание есть. Точно вашу задачу можно решить с помощью скриптов, например на LUA в nginx, но надо пробовать и экспериментировать. На хабре [статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/215235/) по LUA и nginx есть хорошая. А теперь еще и [nginScript](https://habrahabr.ru/post/267955/) есть.